# How to use same entity in different relations in JPA?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have created an entity named `Image`. It holds image metadata etc that I save in the database. Currently I have an `one-to-many` relationship between `Question` and `Image`. So I have declared `@OneToMany` and `@JoinColumn` annotation on the list of images in question entity. This means there is an foreign key in the image table named `question_id` in my case.

I want to use this entity in other relationships too. `User` could have images and so on. However, this would mean that I need a `user_id` column in the image table too. As this grows this seems like a bad approach.

How can I do this? Do I need to use inheritance and create subclasses like `QuestionImage`, `UserImage` and so on?

Or are there other better (and simpler ways)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't define a JoinColumn. The default for one-to-many unidirectional associations is to use a JoinTable (precisely for this reason).

If you don't specify anything other than `@OneToMany(...)`, a JoinTable will be used. You may of course customize its name and its column names using a `@JoinTable` annotation.

Comment: Hmm...but what if both user and question have the same id? Do you need to use a composite primary key in the join table then? Image id + question/user id? Or must it be another column containing some value?

Comment: You create on join table per association with image/ So one join table for "user has images" and another for "question has images".